# Filter a string for valid MySQL Column name

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have been scraping data from a site.

I have this list scraped

```
[' ', '*One child under 12 years old stays free using existing bedding.', '24 hour front desk', 'Bar / Lounge', 'Business centre', 'Concierge', 'Dry cleaning / laundry service', ...
```

This is scraped so far and more (about 20) would be scraped too.

I want to create a column in my Table for every entry in List by getting its first 20 characters.

Here is how I filter these entries to make a valid MySQL column name.

```
column_name = column_to_create[:20].replace(" ","_").replace("/","_").replace("*","_").replace("-","_").replace("$","_").replace("&","_").replace(".","_")
```

I know it does not include many invalid character.

How can I filter to get a valid column name? Any less-code solution or any Reg-Ex ???

Comment: You could just include the column name in backticks.  Then MySQL will accept it.

Comment: No, I do not want `/` `'` `)` and other characters in column name ... not allowed though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `Regex`:

```
column_name = re.sub(r'[-/*$&.\s]+','_',column_to_create[:20])
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> st = "replace/    these**characters---all$$of&them....with_"
>>> re.sub(r'[-/*$&.\s]+','_',st)
'replace_these_characters_all_of_them_with_'
```

Also if there is any other character you want to replace with `_`, just add that character to **square braces** in the **Regex**. Say e.g., you need to replace `#` also. Then **regex** would become `re.sub(r'[-/*$&.\s#]+','_',column_to_create[:20])`.

Comment: This does not remove spaces between characters

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to add the space character `\s` in replacement characters. I've uploaded it now, try again.

Comment: Before you updated, I tried giving a blank space ` ` in regex ... and it also worked ... :) Is it good approach???
And I want also to remove new-lines or anything that makes an in-valid MySQL column name, should be removed from my astring

Comment: `ust add that character to square braces in the Regex`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python has a translate capability you can use to easily change one character into another, or delete characters. I use it something like this (first 3 lines are setup, 4th line is actually using it.)

```
    norm   =  string.maketrans(' _,','---') # space underscore comma to dash
    keep   =  "-@'$%{}[]~#().&^+=/\/:"
    toss   =  string.translate(norm,norm,string.letters+string.digits+keep)

    toName = toName.translate(norm,toss)
```

Comment: M a noob to Python ... dont know what u wrote :P